# PhpStorm namespace to Laravel's app directory

Tags: namespaces, settings, phpstorm

I seem to be having an issue with PhpStorm and Laravel, where for some strange reason, every time that I manually create a new class file it uses the `app` for the beginning of the namespace - even though I've set the app name with `artisan`. When generating files via `artisan` - namespace is correct - it's just when I create files manually from within the PhpStorm.

I'm sure it's an easy fix - I just don't quite know where in the settings is the option to update it.

Comment: Check your `Settings/Preferences | Project | Directories` -- check folders that are marked as "Source". So far it sounds like root folder is marked as Source.

Comment: Also you can invoke "Detect PSR-0 Namespace Roots" http://i.imgur.com/T2r7Aqc.png

Comment: So how should I mark the `app` directory - as `Source`?

Comment: Right click on directory -> Mark directory As -> Sources Root

Comment: Thankx @fuvinan - could you post it as and answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on directory -> Mark directory As -> Sources Root